# Android 2.1: Bluetooth Encryption

Tags: android, encryption, bluetooth

Is a bluetooth connection between a android device and a laptop encrypted by default? The bluetooth server is started on the android smartphone and therfore, the connection is initiated by the laptop.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: That depends... Do you have access to the code executed in the Android smartphone?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is yes...and the comments why can be see in this:

[Bluetooth Secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085394/is-bluetooth-file-exchange-completely-secure)

If you really want to read up on Bluetooth security got to [HowStuffWorks](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/bluetooth1.htm)